# The modal verb Be to

Tags: modal-verbs, periphrastic-modals

Is this sentence correct?

> I am to win the competition.

With this sentence I want to say that I must win the competition.

Comment: @JohnLawler Please don't write answers in comments. Use the answer box.

Comment: @DJClayworth - I don't think you're going to win that one.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> *Must* refers to an obligation; *be to* refers to an expectation. The [periphrastic modal](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/300067/15299) for *must* is *have to*; the periphrastic modal *be to* is one of the ways to paraphrase *will*; mostly it means 'be scheduled/expected to', rather than 'be obligated to'. Forget about the question mark.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/613772/2085).

Answer (score -1):

> **1a)** I am to win the competition?    *or*
>
> **1b)** I am to win the competition.

Would be understood as a question asking if the person's fate is to be the victor or indicating anticipation of this before it happens.

In other words:

> **2a)** Am I to understand that I will win the competition?    *or*
>
> **2b)** I will be selected as the winner of the competition.

To express **intent** to win (confidently, even smugly), you could say:

> I will win the competition.

Note that this exact same sentence *could* mean the same things as 1b or 2b above, so context would determine whether it is inevitable or just your intent.

Comment: So it would be better if I mean that I plan to win the competition, right?

Comment: I updated the answer to better address this. But "I will win the competition" can be used to express intent in a confident manner.