# Is Have To/Has To a verb, auxiliary verb, or modal?

Tags: grammar, verbs, present-tense, auxiliary-verbs

I'm wondering what is the actual verb in this sentence: "I have to study". Is the verb "have" or "study" ? Is the verb "have" and "to study" the infinitive?

Comment: This question is more appropriate for our sister site [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).  Voted to close & move to ELL.

Comment: I think this has already been asked here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300051/is-have-to-a-modal-verb

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, "Have to" is the modal and "study" would be the verb. I believe that in this context, "Have to" even has a different pronunciation.

Comment: My thinking is it's an auxiliary verb for example do and does needs to be implemented depending on the subject. Much like has to and have to depending on the subject. However, when I pose it in a question, 'Does she have to study tonight?' The auxiliary verb is changing 'has to' to 'have to'